# react-native flatlist images flicker when list state updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I have populated a `FlatList` with data fetched from Google's `firebase` backend. The implementation is rather standard, here's a stripped down version:

```
export default class Day extends Component {

state = { data : [], today: false }


componentWillMount = async () => {

    const { today } = this.state;
    const { calendarDb } = this.props

    await calendarDb.onNewAgenda({ 
          day : today
        , then: this.parseOnListed 
    })
}

parseOnListed = blob => {

    const { data } = this.state;
    data.push(blob)
    this.setState({ data: data })
}


renderItem = ({ item }) => 
    <Hour data = {item}/>


render = () => 
    <FlatList  
        data         = {this.state.data}
        renderItem   = {this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor = {item => item.ID}
    />
```

}

The issue is that every time a new `blob` is pushed into `data`, the `<Image/>` component in `<Hour data={item}/>` flickers. This makes the list a no-go in terms of user experience. What gives? `<Hour/>` is standard as well, and more or less look like this:

```
const Hour = ({ data }) => 
   <View>
       <Image source={{uri:data.uri}}/>
       <Text> {data.name} </Text>
   </View>
```

The content of `<Text>` does not flicker, only the image from `<Image .../>`

Comment: try using a keyExtractor to uniquely identify a row, this might be due to the whole flatlist re rendering on state update and images being downloaded again

Comment: In the actual codebase I have `keyExtractor = {item => item.ID  + Math.random()}` . But it still flickers

Comment: why use math.random ? this will make react think that its a new object each time so it might be the issue

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan ok thats it. fixed the problem thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check whether keyExtractor is getting unique ID.
2. Use useCallback

```
<FlatList
    data={data}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <ListItem
        data={item}
        index={index}
        key={index + 1}
        />
    )}
/>
    
const ListItem = useCallback(({ data, index, }) => {
   return ( 
     <View key={item.id}>
     ...
     </View>
   );
}, []);
```

Answer (score 12):

Check whether `keyExtractor` is getting unique ID or not.
The flat list is re-rendering on state update and images are downloaded again. Because, each row is not uniquely identified as said in comments by @Guruparan Giritharan.

Answer (score 2):

I found another reason that triggers this issue, of the FlatList flikering on React native. In my case, it happened every time I updated/changed the state of any function component. So, for instance, I was keeping the fetch results (data) and the next-page-id (for the next paginated fetch) in two separate function components:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [pageId, setPageId] = useState(null);
```

Hence, every time would capture the results of my fetch, I would first set the data update and then the page id. It was the page id update what was causing the flicker.

```
const onEndReachedFetch = async () ={
    fetch(pageId).then(result => {
        setData(result.Data);
        setPageId(result.pageId);
    });
}
```

The fix was just to put the state data together so there is a single update instead. Then react is happy and doesn't flicker when adding new items to the list.

```
const onEndReachedFetch = async () ={
    fetch(pageId).then(result => {
        setResult(result);
    });
}
```

Beware of any side states that you may be updating in the background, as they may also cause the flickering if they are triggered by anything on the FlatList.

Comment: I think React 18 solved this by `Automatic Batching`